# Im trying to change the html code of a website

Tags: html

Im trying to change the html code of a website. As you can see here: https://share-your-photo.com/b12b204e8c

The Code starts with an h3 tag. i want to replace it with a p tag. at beginning with `<p class=`and at the end of the code with `</p>`. But the code turns red at the end. can you give me a solution how i can do?

Comment: the original code itself is wrong semantically speaking. Replacing the h3 tag with a p tag causes an issue because you'll get divs inside p, which is wrong as well. I think you should study about HTML before making any changes.

Comment: so can you please give me a solution how i can replace h3 tag. i dont want it as a h3 tag.

Comment: Just use div's do NOT use h3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see that you had the `<h3></h3>` wrapped around everything and that is not the proper syntax in html. Its called hierarchy. Hierarchy is

> An element that is directly above another element in the hierarchy is
>   called the parent of the element below it. The element below the
>   parent is called the child. When two elements are equal in the
>   hierarchy, they are known as siblings.

*--Thx Google*... A `<h3></h3>` tag can't wrap all of those elements only tags like a `<div>` can or a `<span>`. A `<div>` tag is a block element. So if you have 2 `<div>` tags like this... `<div>HI</div>` and `<div>Hello</div>` "HI" will be on top and "Hello" will be on the bottom but if it were `<span>` It will make it horizontal `<span>Hi</span>` and `<span>Hello</span>` the output will be "Hi Hello". If you check out this link they briefly explain nesting. But there are many many places you can go to understand this [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp[1](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp) Hopefully that helps you! Keep on coding!

Answer (score 0):

You said: "_the code turns red at the end...". The end of what??? Are you trying to edit the code locally in an editor such as sublime, vscode?

Basically, think of an Html document as a Word document that contains titles, subtitles, etc..

In Html documents, we have the following hierarchy structure.

```
<h1>My Page Title</h1>
<h2>My Page Subtitle</h2>
<p>here we can have only text, <strong>bold text</strong>, <i>italic</i>, and other styled text with <span>spanned texts</span></p>

<div>
  <h3>Layouts</h3>
  <p>you can use divs to structure your layout, so, doesn't make sense to have divs inside paragraphs.</p>
  <p>If you want, you can break lines with <br> tags</p>
</div>
```